# Sqlite can not store html with special tag <ul> <li>

Tags: html, angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using sqlite for store html text.

When user login, I read html from database and compile & insert to screen.

Everything working fine, but today I got an error.
When the html text exact this, this can store into sqlite but can not read from cordova sqlite:

```css
<ul>
    <li>improve the supply to organs and tissue, thereby aiding regeneration,</li>
    <li>reduce susceptibility for infection,     </li>
    <li>support the immune system,</li>
    <li>increase physical performance,</li>
    <li>increase mental performance,</li>
    <li>generate physical and mental performance reserves,     </li>
    <li>reduce the consequences of stress,</li>
    <li>reduce burnout.</li>
</ul>
```

I am using https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage
on IONIC Framework

because it not through any error, just dead at :

```
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, parameters).then(function(result) {
            q.resolve(result);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log('DB Error ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            q.reject(error);
        });
```

When read those html text above.

Please help me solve this case.

Comment: Have you inspected the value of `result` in your JavaScript debugger?  What does `q.resolve()` do?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen it's hang at $cordovaSQLite.execute and not return anything

Comment: And what is the query you are running?  Can you run this query directly from SQlite?

Comment: ofcourse, i use sqlite tool to open database and see that record stored normaly, so can not read from it, i can make query in sqlite tool and have result correct with no error.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you give me some advice ?

Comment: Include the actual value of `query`, and also tell us what the `parameters` are.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the success function doesn't run? Have you debugged? Added a `console.log`? Just making sure.

Comment: yes, i'm sure 100% it hang when call into excute function.